# How can I set up an NAS server on my Ubuntu system that would be accessible over the internet?

Tags: 16.04, server, raid, nas

I'm doing a project and I would like to know how can I configure a NAS server for the people involved in the project to upload their files to the NAS via Internet.

I'm doing this in a VM which runs Ubuntu Server 16.04 and it has the drive in which the OS will be installed, and 4 drives (which I would like to be RAID 01).

What I need help with is making this system run an NAS server that can be access through the Internet. How can I do that?

Comment: this question is related to NAT, Port Forwarding and iptables. Ubuntu concerns only with iptables.

Comment: You need to setup the router to able NAS access to internet, this is the question and depending of the fabricant you will be a many options like a upload files on your NAS over internet, the next step will be sincronized the Ubuntu Server with NAS or reverse, tell us who NAS you have.